# Let $a$ be a real number and $\mid x-a \mid < \frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$, then $\mid x \mid > \frac{\mid a \mid}{2}.$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Here's what I got, but I feel like I might not be going in the right direction with this. Can someone guide me, please?

We will prove this directly. That is, we will assume $a$ is a real number and $\mid x-a \mid < \frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$, and we will show $\mid x \mid > \frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$.

We will start with $\mid x-a \mid < \frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$. We will then divide both sides of the inequality by $\mid a \mid$ to get $\frac{x-a}{\mid a \mid}=\frac{1}{2}$. We can then simplify this to $ \mid 1-\frac{x}{a} \mid <\frac{1}{2}$. We then add the additive inverse of 1 from both sides to get $ \mid \frac{-x}{ a } \mid <-\frac{1}{2}$. We then add the additive inverse of $-\frac{1}{2}$ and the additive inverse of $\frac{-x}{\mid a \mid}$ to both sides to get $\frac{1}{2} < \mid \frac{x}{a} \mid$. We can then multiply both sides by $\mid a \mid$ to get $\frac{\mid a \mid}{2} < x$. We can then rewrite this as $x < \frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$ and we can then get $\mid x \mid < \frac{\mid a \mid}{2}$ which completes this proof.

Comment: Wrong approach.  For example, when you divide $|x - a|$ by $|a|$, you get $\frac{|x-a|}{|a|},$ rather than $\frac{x-a}{|a|}.$  The right approach is to (inelegantly) break the problem into two cases: (1) $a \geq 0$ and (2) $a < 0.$

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)? You have $|a| - |x| \le |x-a| < \frac{|a|}{2}$ so $-|x| < \frac{|a|}{2} - |a| = -\frac{|a|}{2} \Rightarrow |x| > \frac{|a|}{2}$.

Comment: I upvoted : nice elegance, in contrast to the *inelegance* that my comment recommended.  The only downside, is that although your answer is valid, it glosses over *why* the conjecture is true.  The inelegant approach would force the OP to examine the situation "case by case", which would improve the OP's understanding of the situation.

Comment: I just learned about that not too long ago, but for some reason, it did not cross my mind while working on this. This helps a lot, thanks for reminding me about that!